# Missing photos when retrieving Users tagged photos facebook-graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve all of the photos that a user is tagged in from Facebook. I have both the user_photos and friends_photos access token but am not getting a full list of photos (i.e. all the photos the user is tagged in).

Below is my fql query:

```
SELECT images, target_type FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject =" + req.user.id + ")ORDER BY created DESC
```

I'm rather confused as some of the photos that are not being retrieved have been uploaded publicly. Basically I am unable to see a pattern among the photos that haven been left out. Could anyone explain why some photos are being left out?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is the settings of each user since according to the answer posted here - [facebook graph api - missing fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406005/facebook-graph-api-missing-fields), 
API access to these things can be turned off at the user's discretion.