# facebook graph api - missing fields

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I'm trying to make a facebook application which deals mostly with posts in facebook groups.

So, when i access the **feed** from my app, some fields are missing. When i access the same post over facebook, those fields are visible.

Eg: A photo uploaded by a user is not visible when accessed via graph. It hides the **photo** field. Later i found that whatever photos that specific user uploaded, I couldn't access it via graph api.

Does anyone know the reason? Does it have something to do with permissions? (I hope not, because i've enabled all app permissions listed by facebook)

Comment: This sounds like an issue of privacy. That user probably set some custom privacy settings on the photos.

Comment: @Lix So the solution would be to ask the user to remove custom privacy settings?

Comment: If that really is the case then yes - but it would not be realistic to  request this from all of your users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FB Developers should expect this. FB users can disable api access to their data on a feature-by-feature basis (in fact, they can disable FB Platform entirely).  For example, they can prevent access to their photos via the api.
This is set in the account settings > Apps > Apps Others Use

[image]
[image]

---